# DBCC CheckDB Consistency error on an empty table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I restored a DB from SQL Server 2000.

I ran `DBCC CHECKDB` on SQL Server 2000, and it did not report any errors.

What could be the reason behind a `DBCC CHECKDB` reporting a consistency error on a empty table in SQL Server 2008?